# Angular Universal 6 SSR Works Locally but Not On Server

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-material2, angular-universal

I have a fully functioning Angular 6 universal app that serves up SEO friendly HTML **locally**.  The `webpack.server.config.js` for my `server.ts` complication has `externals: [/node_modules/],` which means  everything should be bundled in my `dist` folder.

Locally, everything works well.  When I copy my `dist` folder to my Amazon Linux instance and run the same `node server.js` command, the server starts up but requests that require the SSR eventually time out with this error.

`ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: null,
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
  ...`

After much research, the source of this is HTTPS calls happening on the server never complete.  The exact reason why is still a mystery, as is how to fix it since using HTTP is a requirement.

Also, my local and server environments differ only in 1 area.  My openssl version is 1.02 on the server but an older 0.98 locally.  Downgrading my OPENSSL version is not an option.

Anybody else experiencing this?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Check server side logs. If there is any error server side, it won't be because of CORS since it's only implemented in browsers

Comment: To troubleshoot, I'm just running node in the console and looking for any standard output there.  Nothing happens and eventually the error I included above comes after things time out.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am having the same problem with my project